# Splitting a string into 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to split string (using spaces) into 3 columns. code is working but looks bulky, need to know if tere is an efficient way of acheiving the same.

**Important:** I also want to know how can I insert 3 empty colmns without repeating below code 2 more times.

```
Range(startCELL).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

Code for splitting string into 3 columns, at the moment code inserts 1 empty column to the right of active cell.

```
Sub split_string_in_3_columns()
 Dim startCELL  As String, lastCELL As String
 Dim cell As Range, rang As Range
 
 Range("a15").Select
 startCELL = ActiveCell.Address(False, False)
 Range(startCELL).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
 lastCELL = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Address(False, False)
 
 Set rang = Range(startCELL, lastCELL)
 Debug.Print rang.Address
 
            For Each cell In rang
            If (Len(cell.Value) - Len(Replace(cell.Value, " ", ""))) <= 1 Then
                Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, InStr(1, cell.Value, " ") - 1)
                Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - InStr(1, cell.Value, " "))
            Else
                 Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, InStr(1, cell.Value, " ") - 1)
                 Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(cell.Value, InStr(1, cell.Value, " ") + 1, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Search("^", WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell.Value, " ", "^", 2)) - 1 - InStr(1, cell.Value, " "))
                 Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - Excel.WorksheetFunction.Search("^", WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell.Value, " ", "^", 2)))
            End If
            Next cell
                Range(startCELL).Select
End Sub
```

Thank you all for the time and your help.

Comment: Did you try using `Split`? Or text to columns?

Comment: ^^ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: No, I did not use split, thanks it helps . Can you also let me know how can I insert 3 columns without repeating code 2 more times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a demo of using `Split()` to parse the active cell:

```
Sub SplitDemo()
    arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
End Sub
```

[image]

*(same result as Text-to-Columns)*

Here is how to split a cell and put the result downwards:

```
Sub SplitDemoDownwards()
    arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = .Transpose(arr)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thnks for anwering, can you also let me know how to insert 3 columns here >>> Range(startCELL).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert" without repeating this code.